# Plotting two categories in ggplot2 violin R

Tags: r

I have a data set with different categories. Let's say A,B,C and D.

Here is how the data set looks like

```
        V1   V2    V3
    1   NA    1   0.1
    2    2    2   0.2
    3    3   NA   0.1
    4    4    4   0.3
    5   NA   NA   0.4
    6   NA   NA   0.8
    7    7    7   0.2
    8   NA    8   0.1
    9    9   NA   0.6
    10  NA   NA   0.1
```

The lines that:

V1 column is not NA are in category A

V2 column is not NA are in category B

(V1 column is not NA **OR** V2 column is not NA )are in category C

All the line in this dataframe are in category D

In the case of the example above: There are lines that fall into A and C at the same time(like line 3). Line 1 would be in category B and C. Therefore, the number of category C may be less that the number of A+B. All the 10 lines are in category D.

I want use ggplot2 to plot a violin plot of category A,B,C and D together according to the values in V3. (That is A B C D in X-axis and V3 in Y-axis)

Does anybody got a hint? I tried but ggplot2 seems can't not deal with overlapped categories. If the data have another column specified the categories, it would work fine:

```
        V1   V2    V3    Group
    1   NA    1   0.1        B
    2    2    2   0.2        C
    3    3   NA   0.1        A
    4    4    4   0.3        C
    5   NA   NA   0.4        D
    6   NA   NA   0.8        D
    7    7    7   0.2        C
    8   NA    8   0.1        B
    9    9   NA   0.6        A
    10  NA   NA   0.1        D
```

There will be 4 violin but in each violin there are only entries only in that category. The overlapped ones would not be taken into account.

Is there a way to plot the overlap categories in ggplot2? Or is there a way to plot different categories from different dataframes into ONE violin plot? Or do you suggest to plot 4 subset of the original data set and combine the four violin plots together?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This rather belongs to [datascience.se].

Comment: Pipe the data through a processor such as `awk` that adds the category column. Apparently you can then plot the result. Something like `awk -f awkscript datafile | ggplot -` might work

Comment: Yes I can add a group column. But the problem is that category C may have overlap with A/B. I can't find a way to display items in category A and also in category C using the ggplot2 violin plot.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to construct the categories you want.

Data:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
   NA    1   0.1
    2    2   0.2
    3   NA   0.1
    4    4   0.3
   NA   NA   0.4
   NA   NA   0.8
    7    7   0.2
   NA    8   0.1
    9   NA   0.6
   NA   NA   0.1")
```

Transformation:

```
dd$Group <- with(dd,
  ifelse(is.na(V1) & is.na(V2),"D",
         ifelse(!is.na(V1) & !is.na(V2),"C",
                ifelse(is.na(V1),"B","A"))))
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for replying! In your code, are you considering the category C are the lines that both V1 and V2 are not NA? But I want the category C to be (V1 != "NA" **OR** V2!= "NA"). That means there may be overlaps with category C and A/B.